# Terraform apply in GitLab CI/CD only if plan is not empty

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I use Gitlab CI/CD to provision infrastructure with Terraform.
I currently have a 3 stages pipeline (*init*, *plan*, *apply*) that works great with a manual *apply* job.
The *plan* job shares a plan artefact with the *apply* job.

Sometimes the plan is empty (no resource to change) but the *apply* job is still mandatory.
Do you know a way to avoid running the *apply* job when the plan is empty ?
Or to automatically (instead of manually) run the *apply* job when the plan is empty ?

Comment: Ideally instead there would be some approval prior to the `apply`. This could either occur as part of the git workflow automatically post-merge, or within the pipeline itself. This would also prevent applies with no planned changes in addition to the other benefits.

Comment: I also use merge requests to validate plans, but for the merged pipeline, I prefer to keep the `apply` job manual because of the delay between the plan from merged request pipeline and the plan from the main pipeline.
I also intend to use another pipeline that would include many Terraform-based sub-pipelines: many of them would have empty plans (and thus no manual action) while some would have resources changes (and thus manual action).

Comment: Ok so you have already implemented my second suggestion. In that case, it is unclear to me where the issue lies since you could not approve the `apply` job if the plan is empty. Is this an efficiency issue where you would prefer to not even continue the pipeline at all in that situation?

Comment: On a merge request: CI init/plan, then merge request approval in the UI (even on empty plan because it could only be some refactoring/comment...) -> branch merged -> CI init/plan/apply(manual).

I could make the `apply` job automatic instead of manual, but the plan may be different of the one computed during the merge request (if someone changed some resources manually in the meantime, or applied the plan outside of Gitlab).

Comment: So the answer to my question is: yes. Actually, what you could do is store the plan generated during the PR and then apply that post-merge. However, no pipeline tool other than somewhat Jenkins supports that intrinsically, and therefore you would need external storage for it. That would be best practices if you could pull it off though

Comment: To circle back though: you could have a conditional job in GitlabCI for the `apply` based upon whether the plan would have changes or not. Without the config in the question I have to be broad. However, that would solve the problem for you as it currently stands.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's what I was wondering, it's not possible. The conditional jobs in GitlabCI are evaluated at pipeline startup, so no way to make a condition based on a previous job.

Comment: Ok yeah if GitlabCI is declarative like that, then it would not be possible for the reason you stated.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to implement that is by using `-detailed-exitcode` in your terraform plan step. As per Terraform documentation:

```
  -detailed-exitcode  Return detailed exit codes when the command exits. This
                  will change the meaning of exit codes to:
                  0 - Succeeded, diff is empty (no changes)
                  1 - Errored
                  2 - Succeeded, there is a diff
```

As an example, run in your terminal the plan:

```
terraform plan -detailed-exitcode
```

An then run in your terminal:

```
echo $?
```

If the plan contains any changes your value won't be zero.
You just need evaluate that value in your CI/CD with an If statement to decide if you want to run the apply or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that doesn't solve my problem as I need a manual action in Gitlab CI/CD to decide if the plan has to be applied.
Your solution would only work with a single Gitlab job performing the plan and deciding whether to apply the plan or not (thus without manual validation).

Comment: Why would you need to trigger the apply job when you already know that there are no changes? Best practice is to avoid any interaction with your infrastructure if you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

With the use of [GitLab dynamic child pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines) it becomes possible to decide in the parent pipeline if the apply job in the child pipeline should be a manual job. Example:

```yaml
stages:
  - plan
  - apply

# init stage ommited for brevity

plan:
  stage: plan
  script: |
    RC=0
    terraform plan -input=false -out=tfplan -detailed-exitcode || RC=$?
    if [ $RC -eq 0 ]; then   # Succeeded, diff is empty (no changes)
      WHEN=on_success
    elif [ $RC -eq 2 ]; then # Succeeded, there is a diff
      WHEN=manual
    else                     # Errored
      exit 1
    fi
    # Create the child pipeline definition
    tee apply-child-pipeline.yml <<EOF
    apply:
      script:
        - terraform apply -input=false tfplan
      rules:
        - when: "$WHEN"
      # Retrieve terraform plan output (tfplan) and lock file from parent job
      needs:
        - pipeline: "$CI_PIPELINE_ID"
          job: "$CI_JOB_NAME"
    EOF
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - apply-child-pipeline.yml # for the next job
      - tfplan
      - .terraform.lock.hcl

create-apply:
  stage: apply
  trigger:
    strategy: depend
    include:
      - artifact: apply-child-pipeline.yml
        job: plan
```

So the apply job does not go away, but it just automatically runs if there are no planned Terraform changes.

Answer (score 0):

In you plan job, you output your plan file:

```
terraform plan --out planoutput
```

Which you pass as an artifact to your apply job.

Before applying, you can `grep` (I'll let you find the correct `grep` command here) your plan

```
terraform show planoutput | grep Plan
```

And depending on that, do a `terraform apply` or not.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but that doesn't prevent the manual Gitalb job to become automatic on empty plan. The more I think about it, the more I think it's impossible...